# SQL Server slow stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a problem about my stored procedure ... it's slower than SQL execute in SQL Server 2005.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCashBankView]
    @ssql as varchar(15), 
    @from as smalldatetime, 
    @until as smalldatetime, 
    @filter as varchar(250) 
AS
BEGIN           
   select 
      h.code [Kode], h.transDate [Tanggal], 
      isnull(a.description,h.paymentFrom)  [Awal],  
      (case left(h.givenTo, 2) 
          when 'SP' then s.name 
          when 'PT' then p.name 
          when 'CS' then c.name  
          else h.givenTo 
       end) [Akhir],  
      sum(d.amount) as amount,
      h.paymentCode [Transaksi], 
      isnull(b.name,'') [Bank],
      h.refNo [No.Reff], h.description  
   from 
      tbCashBankHeader h  
   left join 
      tbBank b on h.paymentType = b.code  
   left join 
      tbsupplier s on h.givenTo = s.code   
   left join 
      tbPeternak p on h.givenTo = p.code  
   left join 
      tbCustomer c on h.givenTo = c.code  
   left join 
      tbAccount a on h.paymentFrom = a.number   
   left join 
      tbCashBankDetail d on h.code = d.code  
   where 
      h.status <> 'DEL' 
      and left(h.code, 2) = @ssql 
      and h.transDate >= @from and h.transDate <= @until   
      and (h.code like + '%' + @filter + '%' or a.description like + '%' + @filter + '%' or h.description like + '%' + @filter + '%' or s.name like + '%' + @filter + '%' or p.name like + '%' + @filter + '%' or c.name like + '%' + @filter + '%' or h.givenTo like + '%' + @filter + '%' or b.name like + '%' + @filter + '%')  
   group by 
      h.code, h.transdate, a.description, h.paymentfrom,  
      (case left(h.givenTo,2) when 'SP' then s.name when 'PT' then p.name when 'CS' then c.name  else h.givenTo end),  
      h.paymentCode, b.name, h.description, h.refNo    
   order by 
      h.transdate, h.kode
END
```

And I execute from VB.NET with this code

```
data = getDataTable("exec spCashBankView @ssql,@from,@until,@filter", _
                    "@ssql", SqlDbType.VarChar, ssql, _
                    "@from", SqlDbType.DateTime, dtFrom.Value, _
                    "@until", SqlDbType.DateTime, dtUntil.Value, _
                    "@filter", SqlDbType.VarChar, Trim(txFilter.Text))
```

The function

```
Function getDataTable(ByVal ssql As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As Object)
        Try
            flagQuery = True
            data = New DataTable
            data.Reset()
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = ssql
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args) Step 3
                cmd.Parameters.Add(args(i), args(i + 1), 200).Value = args(i + 2)
            Next

            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            adapter.Fill(data)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Send Query:" & Err.Description, , "Fill Xtra Grid")
            flagQuery = False
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
        Return data
    End Function
```

I'm using XtraGridview express from DEV Express.

The problem is: when I'm executing that stored procedure and the result just 448 rows, VB.NET Xtragridview will be slow and freeze around 5 second or more to show that result.

But when I execute it from SQL Server it just takes 1 second max

[image]

thanks for reading and answering my problem....GBU

Comment: Please show us the execution plan of the query

Comment: You need to create a local DataTable. Change 'data = New DataTable' to 'Dim data As New DataTable'.

Comment: my planning just to be fast than now,cuz in VB.NET run that store procedure needed more than 5 second to show all data

@Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå, what do you meant by create a local dataTable?

Answer (score 0):

you might also try adding this after BEGIN in your stored procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
```

These are defaulted in SSMS to ON, but not when you execute an SP.

Answer (score 0):

I try "RECOMPILE" and working.....
VB.NET getdatatable run faster than before....
I got this from [Stored Procedure runs fast after recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811679/stored-procedure-runs-fast-after-recompile)

=SOLVED=