# Stored procedure recompilation SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

My production environment has SQL Server 2016, SP-2 CU-6 Ent. Edition and I am facing SP slowness issue every time. Once I recompile it then it starts working fine but not for so long.
I know the recompilation importance and usage but this shouldn't be that much frequent that every day or twice in a day I have to recompile all the proc.

Is there any permanent fix available? I am planning to apply latest CU but not sure whether it will fix or not. Let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Please share your procedure or query to help with this issue. What I can guess, this could be due to parameter sniffing. refer this link - https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: @MukeshArora I know the reason and significance of recompilation but here it is not related to single stored procedure. I have to recompile multiple stored procedures. I think it's some kind of bug but not sure.

Comment: Maybe this will help [stored-procedure-runs-fast-after-recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811679/stored-procedure-runs-fast-after-recompile) ; [why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday)

Comment: You should compare your "slow" execution plan with the plan generated after recompilation

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable comments. But I don't think these are going to work because this is not the problem related to single proc but for multiple procs in database. I have disabled the prameter sniffing option from DB level configuration which seems reasonable thing in my situation.